# Python 3 - While Loop Breaking

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, break

I have a larger program which uses a lot of `while` loops, and I have come across 2 ways in how to use them. Both produce the same result, but I am wondering which one is perhaps more efficient in terms of using resources etc.

```
def loop_1():
    var = 0 
    while var != 1: # Until 'var' is 1
        var = int(input("> "))

def loop_2():
    while True: # Until 'break' is used
        var = int(input("> "))
        if var == 1:
            break
```

Both loops stop if you enter 1, but does the `break` syntax use more memory and resources than a regular `while` loop in `loop_1()`? I have a big program with a lot of `while` loops which all use the `break` syntax.

Comment: Whether you use `while x:` or `while True: ... if ! x: break` Should not make much of a difference in terms of performance. The problem probably lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either type of loop should be fine. Write what is easiest to read and understand. You might come back 10 years later and will want as little difficulty as possible to comprehend code you have not seen for the past 9 years. Anyone else who comes after you to read the code will be thankful as well if it is clear.

Comment: Ok thanks, yeah I was using the 'break' syntax and I just found it so much easier to comprehend when looking back over it, again I was just curious to whether or not using 'break' to break out of a loop impacted performance. Thanks.